# How can I call two functions in an onChange event handler?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to call two functions in the **onChange** event.

Here is my code:

```
onChange(e){
   const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
   if (e.target.value == '' || re.test(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({value: e.target.value})
   }
}

<input 
  type="text" 
  size="3" 
  defaultValue={ViewHelpers.toFixed(val1, 2)} 
  onChange={(e) => {
    this.handleValueChanges(this.props.valCols[i]);
    this.onChange
  }}
/>
```

I am unable to call these two functions

Comment: looks like the second one isn't a function call, try adding () to the end

Comment: The question says nothing about not accepting characters. Your question is why the function wasn't being called. That's been answered multiple times. You should accept an answer and open a new question for how to not allow characters in an input.

Comment: Unrelated, but your code might be cleaner if you put `this.handleValueChanges(this.props.valCols[i])` inside of the `onChange` function being called. It's easier to read it there instead of inline with the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the second function (execute it):

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  size="3" 
  defaultValue={ViewHelpers.toFixed(val1, 2)} 
  onChange={(e) => {
    this.handleValueChanges(this.props.valCols[i]);
    this.onChange(e);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I tried this check my updated question it allow text that's my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can call `this.handleValueChanges` in your `this.onChange` handler. In the `onChange` prop of your input, you need to bind your `this.onChange` and pass in the `this.props.valCols[i]` value:

```
onChange(value, e){
    this.handleValueChanges(value);
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if (e.target.value == '' || re.test(e.target.value)) {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }
}

<input 
    type="text"
    size="3" 
    defaultValue={ViewHelpers.toFixed(val1, 2)} 
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, this.props.valCols[i])}
/>
```

**EDIT**
If you don't want to allow text and only numbers, you should use a `number` input instead of a `text` input:

```
<input 
    type="number"
    size="3" 
    defaultValue={ViewHelpers.toFixed(val1, 2)} 
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, this.props.valCols[i])}
/>
```

Comment: I tried this check my updated question it allow text that's my problem

Comment: @MyTest Updated answer. Please review.

Comment: @MyTest Check my edit. You should use a number input if you don't want to allow characters.

Comment: Ya I saw but i don't want change type

Answer (score 0):

The second function doesn't have parentheses. Also you're missing the semicolon.

```
<input
  type="text"
  size="3"
  defaultValue={ViewHelpers.toFixed(val1, 2)}
  onChange={(e) => {
    this.handleValueChanges(this.props.valCols[i]);
    this.onChange();
 }}/>
```

Comment: I tried this check my updated question it allow text that's my problem